# How to add physical .aspx page in dotnet nuke site

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

Hi i am exploring dot net nuke these days, my task is to add physical .aspx page in dot net nuke site, for that purpose i add .aspx page in dot net nuke site which i open in visual studio

```
 -> ADD New Item -> .aspx Page
```

and build it

```
-> Debug -> Build Website
```

but when i saw from add page menu it was not showing in root folder or else where.
kindly help me how i add physical .aspx page. And also tell us whether we can ad physical page in dot net nuke or not .thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a physical aspx page and navigate to it but if you're just trying to a page to the site, you shouldn't add a physical .aspx page. You should add the page by logging in as an admin or host user and choosing Add Page from the Control Panel.